# xQuery, getting the value with namespaces?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, xquery

I am just starting with xquery and currently I don't know, why the following is not working. I've created two XML files, they are identically, except that one has namespaces and the other doesn't:

```
<Envelope>
    <Header>
        <JustAValue>12345</JustAValue>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <someBody>
            <ValueIWant>12345678910</ValueIWant>
        </someBody>
    </Body>
</Envelope>


<env:Envelope xmlns:env='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
    <env:Header xmlns:wsa='http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing'>
        <JustAValue>12345</JustAValue>
    </env:Header>
    <env:Body xmlns:wsu='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd' wsu:Id='element-28-1344266615792-223644235'>
        <ns1:someBody xmlns='http://someURL.com' xmlns:ns1='http://someURL.com'>
            <ValueIWant>12345678910</ValueIWant>
        </ns1:someBody>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Both xml files are in a xml field in the database.

Now I try to get the "ValueIWant" and I do it like this:

```
DECLARE @xml xml

Select @xml = completexml from MyDB.dbo.Xml where PKxml = 3 -- XML without namespaces

declare @somevalue nvarchar(max)

set @somevalue = @xml.value('(/Envelope/Body/someBody/ValueIWant/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)');

select @somevalue -- -> 12345678910


Select @xml = completexml from MyDB.dbo.Xml where PKxml = 2 -- XML with namespaces

set @somevalue = @xml.value('
declare namespace env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"; 
declare namespace ns1="http://someURL.com"; 
(/env:Envelope/env:Body/ns1:someBody/ValueIWant/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)');

select @somevalue -- -> NULL
```

**What am I doing wrong here?**

I've played around a bit with the XML:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
    <env:Header xmlns:wsa='http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing'>
        <JustAValue>12345</JustAValue>
    </env:Header>
    <env:Body xmlns:wsu='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd' wsu:Id='element-28-1344266615792-223644235'>
        <ns1:someBody xmlns='http://someURL.com' xmlns:ns1='http://someURL.com'>
            <ValueIWant>12345678910</ValueIWant>
        </ns1:someBody>
        <BodyValue>BodyValue</BodyValue>
        <env:BodyValue>BodyValue</env:BodyValue>
    </env:Body>
    <env:TestValue1>TestValue</env:TestValue1>
    <TestValue2>TestValue2</TestValue2>
</env:Envelope>
```

I can get all the values: BodyValue, TestValue1 and TestValue2. No problem at all, but as soon as I want to change into the ns1 namespace and get ValueIWant, it just returns NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ValueIWant element tag name is in the default namespace (http://someURL.com), because this namespace is bound to the empty prefix by its parent element:

```
<ns1:someBody xmlns='http://someURL.com' ...
```

However in the query there seems to be no default namespace, so that the name test ValueIWant does not match the ValueIWant tag.

Since it is the same URL that is bound to the ns1 prefix, perhaps prefixing ValueIWant with ns1 in your XPath expression would solve the problem?

Alternatively, you could add a

```
declare default element namespace "http://someURL.com";
```

in your query. But using the ns1 prefix should normally work as well, because when comparing names ("QNames"), only the namespace and the local name matter, the prefix is irrelevant.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't change anything.

Comment: The query seems to work here: http://www.zorba-xquery.com/html/demo#EoyKoQIIN13DHhZXxZLixw7g6dI= but I needed to wrap the XML in a document node. If it is not the case in your DB (i.e., the root is the element node env:Envelope), then maybe removing the first step of your XPath expression would help?

Comment: Actually, it must be something else, because there is a leading slash making the path absolute (and it does work in the namespace-less variant).

Comment: Yes, must be something else. :(

Comment: HA! I've played around a bit and now it's working. Think it somehow had something to do with the default namespace. No idea why it didn't work the first time.